# Trying to iterate through key, val dictionary, and matching the key with another for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a key, val `dict` like this:

```
choices = {'first': 1, 'second': 2, 'third': 3}
```

Then a set of divs like this:

```
<div class="choice_result">
    <p class="choice_result_text">first<p/>
    <span></span>
</div>

<div class="choice_result">
    <p class="choice_result_text">second<p/>
    <span></span>
</div>

<div class="choice_result">
    <p class="choice_result_text">third<p/>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

I want to iterate through each `.choice_result_text`, and if that `.choice_result_text` == `key`, I want to change the html of that `span` to `val`. Right now, my jQuery code (in an ajax success function) looks like this:

```
result = $('.choice_result_text');

$.each(data.choices, function (key, val) {
            $.each(result, function () {
                if(result.html() == key) {
                    j = $('.choice_result').find('span').html(key);
                    j.html(val);
                }
            })
        });
```

Right now, this code turns every `span` to the first `val` in choices (`1`). Any idea how to make it work properly?

Comment: why not use an id in the tags with the key of `choices`?

Comment: not sure what you mean.

Comment: `<p class="choice_result_text" id ="first">first<p/>`, for example.

Comment: the divs are dynamically created. I just put first, second, third there for a placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues

- Your HTML has `<p/>` which is not a closing tag, but a tag that opens a new `p` element. You should change this to `</p>`
- It is a waste of time to loop over the `choices` properties, when the advantage of object properties is that you can access them directly, without looping. So skip the outer loop, and find the object value inside the inner loop (without the need of an additional loop)
- don't use `.html()` when you are working with plain text. There is a separate method for that: `.text()`.
- `$('.choice_result').find('span')` will find all the `span` tags with an ancestor of the given class. Instead you should use the current context of the selection that was already made with `each`. jQuery sets `this` to the matched element, and with `next` you can find the next sibling.
- You can use `$(selector).each(...)` instead of `$.each($(selector),...)` which is a bit more readable in my opinion.

Here is a version that does the job:

```js
var choices = { first: 1, second: 2, third: 3 };

$('.choice_result_text').each(function () {
    var key = $(this).text();
    if (key in choices) {
        $(this).next('span').text(choices[key]);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="choice_result">
    <p class="choice_result_text">first</p>
    <span></span>
</div>

<div class="choice_result">
    <p class="choice_result_text">second</p>
    <span></span>
</div>

<div class="choice_result">
    <p class="choice_result_text">third</p>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is the best answer. But would you be able help make a slight adjustment to the jQuery code. My `choices` is now a list tuple like so: `choices = [('first', 1), ('second', 2), ('third', 3), ('fourth', 4)`. I tried to do it but couldn't get it

Comment: JavaScript has no tuples, just arrays. The value you provide here for `choices` is invalid syntax in JavaScript.

Comment: Right. The reason I asked is because I'm trying to sort the dictionary based on its values (in descending order). So would you know how to do that for the original dictionary?

Comment: If you can assume ES6 support, then `choices = new Map; choices.set('first', 1);` would keep the insertion order, and still give you direct access by key:  `choices.get('first') === 1`. Alternatively, you can use nested arrays: `choices = [['first', 1], ['second', 2], ...]`, but then you don't have that direct access, and need to iterate through the array to find a pair by its first value. NB: Maps and these arrays of pairs convert easily to eachother. But if you have questions about that, it would be good to post that as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop each `div` and check if object has text of `p` as key with `hasOwnProperty` and then add its value to `span`

```js
var choices = {
  first: 1,
  second: 2,
  third: 3
}
$('.choice_result').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).find('p').text().trim()

  if (choices.hasOwnProperty(text)) {
    $(this).find('span').html(choices[text])
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="choice_result">
    <p class="choice_result_text">first<p/>
    <span></span>
</div>

<div class="choice_result">
    <p class="choice_result_text">second<p/>
    <span></span>
</div>

<div class="choice_result">
    <p class="choice_result_text">third<p/>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

An attribute that contained the text value would make this very simple using selectors only

```
<div class="choice_result">
    <p class="choice_result_text" data-text="first">first<p/>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

JS

```
$.each(choices, function(key, val){
   $('.choice_result_text[data-text="' + key + '"]').next().text(val);
})
```